# Debugging vim keypresses

Tags: vim

I was wondering if there is a way to see what commands are run by vim when I press a certain key.

In particular I am facing the rather weird behavior that vim does not execute my redefined behavior to switch between splits. I have the following lines in my .vimrc that remap the movement keys:

```
map <c-j> <c-w>j
map <c-k> <c-w>k
map <c-l> <c-w>l
map <c-h> <c-w>h
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
```

According to these remappings I want to be able to switch between splits by simply using ctrl + one of the movement keys.

It works for all keys except for `j` and I wanted to find out if that key might have been remapped by one of my installed plugins.
Is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find out more about the mapping using the following command:

```
:verbose nnoremap j
```

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it up - nnoremap disables the recursive remapping of previous mappings, so changing nnoremap j gj to nmap j gj fixed the problem and both mappings work now.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about any really debuging feature but you can try `:verbose map <shortcut>`. It often provides useful info.